# MySQL db inherited without normalization in one table, but I need to query off of it

Tags: php, mysql

table1 has hero_id with 6 columns called item1...item6 with item_id's for values.

These items each have different "costs" found in table2, structured with the item_id key and item_cost as a field.

What I want to do is get the total value of the inventory at the hero level (i.e. add up the values of the 6 items). However, without using a case statement for 200 items, I don't know how I would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help:

```
select t1.hero_id, sum(t2.cost)
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.item_id in (t1.item1, t1.item2, t1.item3, t1.item4, t1.item5, t1.item6)
group by t1.hero_id;
```